# Исключить из массива одинаковые элементы с сохранением значения

Tags: php

Есть такой массив:

```
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'XAU/USD' => 
      array (
        'BUY' => '142',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'EUR/USD' => 
      array (
        'BUY' => '143',
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'EUR/USD' => 
      array (
        'SELL' => '144',
      ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'XAU/USD' => 
      array (
        'BUY' => '145',
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Из этого массива нужно получить такой массив:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'XAU/USD' => 
      array (
        'BUY' => '142, 145',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'EUR/USD' => 
      array (
        'BUY' => '143',
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'EUR/USD' => 
      array (
        'SELL' => '144',
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Конкретно в случае приведенном в примере, в массиве два раза есть значение **XAU/USD** и у них значение **BUY**, если есть повторяющиеся значения - их соединяем в 1, и пишем ид через запятую.

Comment: Может для `EUR/USD` значения `BUY` и `SELL` поместить в один массив?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov так не пойдет. мне нужен вывод их два раза если у первой SELL а у второй BUY, если эти значения разные - то это совсем разные значения(хоть и называются одинаково)

Comment: Я не говорю объединить. Я говорю поместить в один массив `'EUR/USD' => ['BUY' => '143', 'SELL' => '144']`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov так тоже не пойдет... нужен именно мой вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пример в песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b0d2a9a256460457f8ffb3745db4f76fb9e8fd5e)

```
$output = [];
$i = 0;
foreach(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr) as $cur => $a) {
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        $output[$i++][$cur][$k] = implode(',',(array)$v);
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: а как мне с ним работать? то есть хочу теперь что то вроде цикла: `{ $output['valuta']; $output['id']; }`

Comment: @Денис Как с массивом работать) Вы же массив хотели такой как вам нужно. Вот реализация

Answer (score 2):

Уверенны что вам нужен именно такой формат как описали? А то просто смержить их дело простое, а вот отформатировать как вам хочется прийдется еще одну итерацию делать. Да и не лучшая практика айдюки через запятую хранить

```
$exchange = [
    [
        'XAU/USD' => [
            'BUY' => 142,
        ],
    ],
    [
        'EUR/USD' => [
            'BUY' => 143,
        ],
    ],
    [
        'EUR/USD' => [
            'SELL' => 144,
        ],
    ],
    [
        'XAU/USD' => [
            'BUY' => 145,
        ],
    ],
];

$merged = [];

foreach ($exchange as $row) {
    $pair = key($row);
    $action = key($row[$pair]);
    $merged[$pair][$action][] = $row[$pair][$action];
}

print_r($merged);

$output = [];

foreach ($merged as $pair => $actions) {
    foreach ($actions as $action => $values) {
        $output[] = [
            $pair => [
                $action => implode(',', $values),
            ],
        ];
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Вызов был принят!

Comment: угу, неплохо...  а как теперь работать с каждым элементом. например из массива под номером 0 (первый) мне по отдельности нужно получить каждое значение ...

Comment: :D Действительно, через запятую в строке не удобно-жеж. Минусовать надо такие ответы!

Comment: @Денис ну если вам надо в одну строчку, то как-то так: `var_dump(explode(',', $output[0][key($output[0])][key($output[0][key($output[0])])]));` Если хотите красивее и перебором, то `foreach` как обычно

Comment: @Денис Поэтому я и сделал два **print_r**, чтоб было видно что после первого перебора, получается то что вам нужно, вот просто поверьте на слово))

Comment: По идеи я хотел получить нечто вроде **цикл { валюта,  BUY(или SELL), ид }**

Comment: @Денис Вам график что-ли со свечами отрисовать нужно по каждой паре?

Answer (score 2):

Накостылено за одну иттерацию:

```
$array = array (
    0 => array('XAU/USD' => array('BUY' => '142')),
    1 => array('EUR/USD' => array('BUY' => '143')),
    2 => array('EUR/USD' => array('SELL' => '144')),
    3 => array('XAU/USD' => array('BUY' => '145'))
);

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $key = key($value);
    $key2 = key($value[$key]);
    if ( ($key2 == 'BUY') && (isset($result[$key . $key2])) ) {
        $result[$key . $key2][$key]['BUY'] .= ', ' . $value[$key][$key2];
    } else {
        $result[$key . $key2] = [$key => $value[$key]];
    }

}
var_dump(array_values($result));
```

И чуть чуть усложненный вариант, если на входе могут быть бесполезные дубли:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $key = key($value);
    $key2 = key($value[$key]);
    if ($key2 == 'BUY') {
        if (isset($result[$key . $key2])) {
            $result[$key . $key2][$key]['BUY'] .= ', ' . $value[$key][$key2];
        } else {
            $result[$key . $key2] = [$key => $value[$key]];
        }
    } else {
        $result[] = [$key => $value[$key]];
    }

}
var_dump(array_values($result));
```

Отвязываемся от слова 'BUY', т.е. если надо чтобы при совпадении SELL, тоже было объединение:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $key = key($value);
    $key2 = key($value[$key]);
    if (isset($result[$key . $key2])) {
        $result[$key . $key2][$key][$key2] .= ', ' . $value[$key][$key2];
    } else {
        $result[$key . $key2] = [$key => $value[$key]];
    }

}
var_dump(array_values($result));
```

Вывод:

```
$result = array_values($result);
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $key = key($value);
    $key2 = key($value[$key]);
    //  Вывести валюту
    var_dump($key);
    //  Вывести тип
    var_dump($key2);
    //  Выведет все ключи
    var_dump(explode(', ', $value[$key][$key2]));
    //  Выведет только те, где список (то что мы объединяли)
    $arr = explode(', ', $value[$key][$key2]);
    if (count($arr) > 1) {
        var_dump($arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я тоже вначале думал через конкотенацию сделать). Но кажется мне что топикстартер занимается ерундой)

Comment: @Ninazu а вдруг, что-то серьезное? :О

Comment: Когда что-то серьезное, то приемлемы более гибкие решения. Явно костыль какой-то. Так чтоб вот вставить фикс и не трогать остальное

Comment: тот же вопрос что и ко второму ответу: `а как теперь работать с каждым элементом. например из массива под номером 0 (первый) мне по отдельности нужно получить каждое значение ...`

Comment: @Денис ну если вам надо в одну строчку, то как-то так: `var_dump(explode(',', $result[0][key($result[0])][key($result[0][key($result[0])])]));` Если хотите красивее и перебором, то `foreach` как обычно))

Comment: Можете пожалуйста пример привести с foreach, голова уже кипит,  запутался.... :|

Comment: @Денис добавил в ответ